# iPhone CoreData - How to fetch managed objects, and sorting them ignoring case?

Tags: iphone, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

Does anyone know how to fetch some results sorting them alphabetically but ignoring case?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Thank you for your reply, but I need to sort the result of a simple "query" ignoring case. Your suggestion applies for searching and comparing.

SQL speaking, I need an `ORDER BY firstName ASC`, and this command must be case insensitive for my usage.

I have done some Googling and I ended reading the [NSSortDescriptor Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and I could find the answer for my question. The solution is setting a selector to the sort descriptor as follow:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I hope it will be useful for more people.

Comment: Don't forget that colon after caseInsensitiveCompare:

Comment: I tested this with [SQL logging enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6428693/1402846). Turns out that iOS is smart enough to do the sorting in SQL instead of in memory, by putting `COLLATE NSCollateNoCase`, or `COLLATE NSCollateLocaleSensitiveNoCase` for `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, after `ORDER BY`. Tested on simulator with iOS 6, and device with iOS 7.

Comment: For those of you looking for a > xCode 7 and Swift solution: `[NSSortDescriptor(key: "string", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))]`

Answer (score 10):

If the app is localized in several languages, please consider using the `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` selector instead of `caseInsensitiveCompare`. It will have the effect to avoid the letter 'é' to be after the letter 'e'.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [NSPredicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795), but basically use [c] to ignore case:

```
@"firstName BEGINSWITH[c] $FIRST_NAME"
```

Comment: Hey Ben, Thanks!

I could find the answer for my question. I posted it here. Cheers, VFN

Answer (score 4):

Swift Version:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))
```